# What causes repeating push notification alerts on iOS 7?

Tags: notifications, ios

I recently updated to IOS 7, now every time I use an app I get a message saying Connect to iTunes to use push notifications " Whatsapp" (And Other Apps) notifications may include alerts, sounds and icon badges, how do I get rid of these once an for all

Comment: Tony - did everything resolve for you as soon as the traffic from the massive upgrade stampede cleared out?

Comment: Logging out and in the account in the Music app does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What happened is somehow the authentication token on your device that should be installed on OS upgrade got corrupted/deleted. I believe currently, the only fix is to restore and restore backup. I haven't seen a way of getting back that token without doing a restore.

Answer (score -1):

I seen different people saying that you have to back up, factory restore the phone, then restore your backup onto the phone and it'll work.. 
It's so much work but if it works then it'll be worth it

Comment: Can you elaborate upon this, providing links or images to support your answer?

Comment: Here's one, for example: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23021909#23021909

Comment: I had the same problem. I resetted and restored the pone and now it finally works again